# Compile error in WordCount.java with CDH4 pseudo distributed mode

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, word-count

I have just copied the `WordCount.java` source code from the examples directory and I am trying to compile it. But I am getting the error

```
WordCount.java:61: error: cannot access Options
String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
                     ^
class file for org.apache.commons.cli.Options not found
1 error
```

**I have not changed anything in the code.**

Comment: How are you compiling it? You obviously need to include the cli library in your class path

Comment: so how can we exceute it using command line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `commons-cli-1.2.jar` to your classpath. Download it from Apache [link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/download_cli.cgi) if you don't see it on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

hadoop common cli is present in the lib folder.

Please go through the following command:

```
javac -classpath hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar:lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar -d tmp/playground/classes tmp/playground/src/WordCount.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **commons-cli-1.2.jar** to your project.
Right-click on your project and choose **build path -> configure build path** and then choose the library from **Hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.2\share\hadoop\common\lib**.